# How to average by column avoiding if any null

Tags: case, average, union, coalesce, isnull

Suppose I have a table as below in SQL Server
[[image: I want the average of column C to H in I. If you see the average of country Albania, its showing null as column C,D,E,F are null, but I want to see the average of G and H in I 1]

Comment: Is it in excel.or JavaScript?

Comment: You meant  by row right? You want the average in TotalScore even if the name is wrong? And this is in Memory, in a Database, in an Excel Sheet?